# How to custom ImageButton's image?

Tags: android, customization, imagebutton, android-drawable

I allow the App's User to change the ImageButton's pictures from the drawable folders?

It's possible?

I want associate this action after `onLongClickListener`,
I put in the `Drawable` folder about 3 or 4 pictures(png) and the User can choose one for its `ImageButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. On onLongClickListener click, you can pop up the option and then put a switch statement and put the following for each of the cases:

```
aButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
```

Here is the more detailed answer:

Put the following at the bottom of the layout (just before the last closing layout tag)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/imagebuttonselectorlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="@android:color/black" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/image2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Then, in the java class file, add the following lines:

```
FrameLayout mFrameLayout;
ImageButton mImageButton1;
ImageButton mImageButton2;

mFrameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonselectorlayout);
mImageButton1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton1);
mImageButton2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgButton2);
```

For the onLongClick of the main image button

```
mImageButton1.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Add the following lines in the same file to complete the functionality:

```
mImageButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mainImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});

mImageButton2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mainImageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        mFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks rahulritesh, 
but whith this solution the User can't choose more than one image, I think (if I understand correctly),
I want to choose between more pictures

Comment: Why can't you do that? For every image, you have an id and then you can do whatever you want based on the selection.

Comment: You'have reason, how can give the User's possibility to choose?

Comment: Use `FrameLayout` and then make it visible on the onLongClickListener. In the new layout, add all the images as ImageButtons and then on the onClick, make the visibility of the FrameLayout as gone and set the imageresource of the main image button as the one of the clicked button.

Comment: Thanks for your solution,
I marked as the best solution.
But I have no idea how to do what you say! : )